# What tree does this leaf belong to?

Tags: identification, trees

I came across this tree many times in Zurich but I wasn't able to find the name. Any suggestions?

[image: Leaf in autumn colors]

Comment: I agree, but how would someone with that leaf find the referenced post?

Comment: It's more about merging the duplicates than saying the asker did wrong. He wouldn't have been able to find the referenced post but now it's important to merge them so there still remains effectively one reference post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The leaf shape indicates Liriodendron tulipifera, but there is some variation in leaf shape with these plants. The ever present feature is the dip in the top of the leaf shape though, but other features of the tree will confirm or deny this ID, such as shoot shape/colour, bark colour/pattern, keys or seeds, colour and shape of flowers, overall growth habit. The link below is a descriptive list of features of this plant, with some photographs

http://www.ibiblio.org/openkey/intkey/web/LITU.htm

Comment: Thank you for the great link! My reputation is not high enough to upvote.

Comment: As described in the link but for reference: Common names include "tulip tree," "tulip poplar," and "yellow poplar" though not a true poplar. Brilliant flowers in springtime. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liriodendron